# Linear Algebra: Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am a bit confused how to tell if a set form a subspace. I know the properties just not how to apply them. My question is: 
Does {(a, 2a, a^2)} form a subspace?

Comment: A subspace of $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What is $a$?  The question is not fully posed.

Comment: @Dave Yes subspace of $ℝ^3$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry... still getting the hang of this.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Partly why I am so confused... this was all I was given to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the question is

> Does the set $X=\{(a,2a,a^2) | a \in \mathbb R\}$ form a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$?

The answer is **no**, since it is not closed under multiplication by a scalar

$$(1,2,1) \in X$$
$$2 \cdot (1,2,1) = (2,4,2) \not \in X$$